# heroku local brokes without changes/reasons

Tags: javascript, heroku, heroku-cli

I use heroku in my React project for local tests.

Procfile.dev:

```
    web: make start-backend
frontend: make start-frontend
```

So, i started it local with "heroku local" command and it worked - started webpack, webpack-dev-server, then application.

Today I got an answer:

```
√ chatty % heroku local
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
```

What could be the reason? Nothing changed, Procfile still on place, commans inside same.

Answer (score 0):

I found, that heroku accidentaly could not see local Procfile.dev
When I set is directly it was OK.

```
heroku local -f=Procfile.dev
```

Still - why it can't see the file?